# how start another activity when java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, android-activity, out-of-memory

My app run in most of devices but in some of device dont run and in Mainactivity.java The error is

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

I want in **SplashScreen.java** if dont run **Mainactivity.java**, run another Activity for example **Main2.activity**

I use this code but does not work:

```
        try {
         Intent mainactivity = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainactivity);
      }
      catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
         Intent main2 = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Main2.class);
        startActivity(main2);
      }
```

please help

```
my logcat:

    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394): Process: ir.maddahha.imamalip, PID: 1394
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:15303)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at ir.maddahha.imamalip.Main.onCreate(Main.java:43)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    10-22 08:32:28.311: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't recover from `OutOfMemoryError`. This error means your app used all available memory and OS can't allocate more for you. Your best shot is to try to investigate source of the problem. You might have some memory leaks, so try to fix that.